# Print as it is input from form django

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a model :

```
 class somemodel(models.Model):
      message=models.TextField()

      def __str__(self):
         return self.message
```

now i have make a form for this model and took input from user . say user is giving input like bellow:

```
  Hi i am a djago developer and i am developing a website . 

  Bellow are my contact details:

   Address: xyz
   mobile:123456
   pin:1234
```

But when i print out the out put this is coming like bellow.

```
   Hi i am a djago developer and i am developing a website . 
   Bellow  are  my contact details: Address: xyz mobile:123456 pin:1234
```

Is it possible to print the input given by the user as it is it have typed .Kindly suggest .

Comment: bro , i said i have made a form for the model and took input from user and save in my database . then i again pull out the data and publish it on my webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with how the text is input or stored.

HTML always ignores whitespace, including line breaks. If you want to display text with line breaks, you need to insert the HTML tags for line breaks.

Luckily there is a built-in Django template tag that will convert line breaks to HTML tags; unsurprisingly it is called `linebreaks`. So, if you're passing the text to the template as `message`:

```
{{ message|linebreaks }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text editor for your TextField for saving the text as html.
`django-ckeditor` seems a good option.
https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor